# Spring Tool Suite(STS) desktop entry for ubuntu

Tags: ide

How to create desktop entry for Spring Tool Suite in Ubuntu?.Want to open the IDE from desktop.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Open terminal
- Type *gedit* and press enter
- Paste the below code in gedit

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Name=sts
  Comment=Spring Tool Suite
  Icon=/home/user/sts-bundle/sts-3.8.2.RELEASE/icon.xpm
  Exec=/home/user/sts-bundle/sts-3.8.2.RELEASE/STS
  Terminal=false
  Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
  StartupWMClass=STS
  ```
- Change the path in above code to your path
- Save the file with ***.desktop*** extension
- Right click the file >properties>permissions
- Tick Allow executing file as program

Comment: Why it complaints `No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/usr/local/sts/jre/bin/java
java in your current PATH` after creating and clicking shortcut. Were I'm able to perform java -version at every terminals.

Comment: @Gopal00005 This may happen because STS can't find any JVM. Please have a look into below link. This may help to solve the issue . 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095666/5875797

Answer (score 11):

For Spring Tool Suite 4 you can use the following. `StartupWMClass` is important if you want the new window to open on the same dock icon (if you don't set `StartupWMClass`, it will add a new icon at the end of the dock for the new open window).

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Spring Tool Suite 4
Comment=Spring Tool Suite 4
Exec=/sts_folder_path/SpringToolSuite4
Icon=/sts_folder_path/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Spring Tool Suite 4
```

Tested using Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: And remember that you can copy/move it to `~/.local/share/applications/` so it is accessible when searching in Unity on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

On debian 9 you have to place the .desktop file at /usr/share/applications directory and run sudo  update-desktop-database.
You can refer to [stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211005/create-launcher-shortcut)

Comment: Moving .desktop file to the `/usr/share/applications` worked on `Ubuntu 20.04` as well

Comment: This is the important bit that most answers have missed!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, the important bit is the `StartupVMClass=SpringToolSuite4` had to match the executable in the line `Exec=/home/johan/bin/sts-4.13.1.RELEASE/SpringToolSuite4 %u`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.1
Name=Spring Tool Suite 4
Comment=Spring Tool Sutie 4.13.1
Exec=/home/johan/bin/sts-4.13.1.RELEASE/SpringToolSuite4 %u
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/eclipse+command;x-scheme-handler/eclipse+mpc;
Icon=/home/johan/bin/sts-4.13.1.RELEASE/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;Development;IDE;
StartupWMClass=SpringToolSuite4
```

Otherwise another icon opened up.

Answer (score 0):

- Open terminal
- Type gedit and press enter
- Paste the below code in gedit

```html
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=STS
Comment=Spring Tool Suite
Icon=/opt/sts-4.8.1.RELEASE/icon.xpm
Exec="/opt/sts-4.8.1.RELEASE/SpringToolSuite4"
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=STS
```

- Change the path in above code to your path
- Save the file with .desktop extension
- Right click the file >properties>permissions
- Tick Allow executing file as program

Answer (score 0):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Spring Tool Suite 4
Comment=Spring Tool Suite 4
Icon=/your_folder/sts-4.11.1/icon.xpm
Exec=/your_folder/sts-4.11.1/SpringToolSuite4
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Spring Tool Suite 4
```

- Save the file with .desktop extension in your desktop
- Right click => Properties => "Allow Executing as a program"
- Right click => "Allow launching". <= The Solution

Answer (score 0):

STPE 1: `cd Desktop`

STEP 2: `touch STS.desktop`

STEP 3:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=STS
Comment=Spring Tool Suite
Icon=Location/sts-4.12.0.RELEASE/icon.xpm
Exec="Location/sts-4.12.0.RELEASE/SpringToolSuite4"
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=STS
```

STEP 3: `chmod u+x STS.desktop`