# A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Dbeaver. No Java virtual machine

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, dbeaver

Java Virtual Machine not found while installing dbeaver tool in the system. What will do to recover from it ?.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you installed ***zip*** archive or ***tar.gz*** archive of the ***dbeaver*** then

- Go to dbeaver directory (Directory created after extraction of archive)
- open dbeaver.ini in a text editor
- Type the following at the top of that file

  ```
  -vm
  copy & paste your java path here (up to bin)

  eg:
  -vm
  /home/admin/jdk1.8.0_131/bin
  ```
- Save the file
- Done

Answer (score 1):

Windows 11, Dbeaver Community Version 23.3.1, after opted out to add Java at installation, in `<dbeaver_installation_folder>/dbeaver.ini` file I've added the first 2 lines:

```
-vm
C:\\Users\\<user_folder>\\.jdks\\openjdk-21\\bin
-vmargs
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.vm=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.ssl=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.jgss=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.peer=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.sql/java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED
-Xms64m
-Xmx1024m
-Ddbeaver.distribution.type=exe
```

Please modify the second line with your path to the java `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in windows 10 when I try to update DBeaver. I manage to solve it by downloading the `Windows 64 bit (installer)` in the official website and install it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling dbaver and install again. If you have still problem with it try to solution what I did.